# Can somebody tell me what is going on with my materials/shaders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fbx, urp

This is the first time I'm using the URP and, upon importing my own fbx models into Unity, I've noticed that they get this strange shadow-y look that only seems to be getting worse and worse:

[Problem I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c46Le.png)

[Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRyIK.png)

This only happens in scene view and it is extremely visible when, for instance, I open a prefab to edit it, sometimes to the extent that any cave-like insets (not sure how else to describe it, see second image) in my models are almost completely covered in shadows. Is this an issue with the shader ? Please do help me out if you can on how to remove this/make it better to the eye in the scene view so that it is easier to edit them, and let me know if you need additional info as I'm not even sure what to include here.

Thanks !

PS: I tried changing the shaders to, for example, Standard shader, of the materials, but I only kept getting pink-colored models (mind you, I'm not very experienced with models and shaders in general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [post-processing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@10.0/manual/integration-with-post-processing.html)?

This looks like the Post-Processing "[Ambient Occlusion](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@10.0/manual/post-processing-ssao.html)" effect.

If so, tweak the effect "intensity" value lower.

Comment: You guided me in the right direction, thanks ! I was confused why it was happening in the Scene View at all, and then I checked the URP settings and, upon turning off Screen Space Ambient Occlusion, the effect disappeared. However, I would like this effect to be on in the Game Mode but not in the Scene view, so I'm gonna see if that's possible. Thanks again !

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Just vote this answear up and select it as the best one, so your question is tagged as solved.